# When is XML parsing with a DOM tree a good thing?

Tags: xml, dom, language-agnostic, architecture

I am puzzled with the idea of looking at XML through the DOM glasses.

Probably like most people, my first approach to XML was building a parser with a DOM interface. However after many years I am not any longer sure why I should use a DOM based parser.

I usually find myself these cases:

1. I must only read an XML file. I can only think of xpath and XML queries
2. I must only write. The latest generation of any template engine can do a better job
3. I must read and write XML. This can be either:

   3.1 symptom of pure laziness for not wanting to learn SQL and tools like SQLite.

   3.2 A case where the application data is tree-like modeled. Because of this reason there are XML databases out there.

   3.3 A case where you must transform the structure. Here XSLT rules

Some ORM can also help with points 2 and 3. At point 3 I have seen many self made implementations of different maturity levels

1. Read and dump into memory. Read objects and dump back to XML. Both as independent processes
2. Read, shape your tree and provide a self backed interface to your objects. Keep a pointer to a DOM node and reuse the already parsed tree to write back modifications
3. Like point 2 but people know about the existence of some nice patterns such as active record

but at even at level 3. I am not sure why DOM must be used.

In which cases is actually implementing a DOM parser based the best approach to a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want a document object model if

1. Access to any part of the model at any moment should be possible.
2. The actual markup structure should be retained, rather than some abstraction of it.

If you just need some values from the XML, you'd use XPath or XQuery. If you have strict input-to-output processing requirements you'd find XSLT to be more suitable. If you just need to parse the XML once and act on its contents then SAX would be a better choice. If the XML is used to represent structured data and you want that, some abstraction (like what JAXB offers for Java) is easier to handle.

But sometimes, what we're really interested in is the actual markup + content and we must have a full model in memory. Like in a browser. Without a DOM representation of (X)HTML pages, JavaScript manipulation would be much harder and probably not nearly as performant.

Also mind that DOM was used when my first point above applied but before there were quite enough tools to provide an abstraction layer. In Java, people tended to use DOM or similar solutions like JDOM and DOM4J frequently, which would sometimes be problematic for large documents. But with the advent and maturation of JAXB, the preferred method for dealing with data encapsulated in XML has become turning it into a much more natural Java representation.

So some use of DOM is actually legacy stuff, but there are legitimate uses. In my personal opinion, it's usually the last thing you would (and should) look at for XML processing, what with the huge amount of specific tools for any conceivable task out there.

**EDIT:** in response to the further inquiry. Do keep in mind that while I'll try to be as accurate as possible in my explanations, I'm not a specialist in some of these things, nor have I read all relevant specifications. So I'll try to keep assumptions to a minimum.

Let's conjure up some scenario for my first point. I've got an XML document that maintains a large amount of settings relevant to some application. The application will at various points wish to retrieve some of these. This could be at any time and the required setting could be at any place in the XML document. How do I get them from the XML?

XPath could definitely be the answer, as you stated in your comment. But the question is, what are we going to evaluate the XPath expression on?

One thing you could do is embed the XPath expression in an XSLT stylesheet and run your XML through that. Or if the XPath API that's available offers the possiblity, just send a SAX stream through there. The problem is that either way we're parsing all or at least part of the XML document each and every time. Suppose you needed 100 pieces of data from the XML and 30 of those are located near the end of the document. That's 30 times you're sending the entire document through a parser, 30 times every piece of markup must be properly interpreted. In a bad case, the XML document is a file on disk and you're trashing your performance with excessive disk access.

Now imagine we used DOM instead. The downside is, the entire XML document resides in memory and eats up some RAM. The upside is... the entire XML document resides in memory! And in a structured way that doesn't require markup to be properly parsed any more, since we've got "element" and "attribute" objects. Everything's been chewed into edible chunks. If we unleash our XPath on that a hundred times, that's 100 fast queries to memory. Particularly if the DOM implementation is smart enough to do some indexing regarding element and attribute names and values. Think of the difference like this: having memorized a book's structure and being capable of quickly leafing to the right chapter for looking something up, versus having to start reading the book from the beginning every time simply because you want some piece of info that turns out to be in chapter 10.

Then for the second point. Your question there is how that related to the rest of my explanation. I think the best use-case to look at here is DOM in web browsers.

Suppose you wanted a dynamic web page, that can run some JavaScript to let you alter it in the browser, without page reloads. All nice clean Web 2.0 stuff. The question is, how're we gonna do that. Imagine we went back to the approach of simply having a large string in memory that represents the (X)HTML. In order to alter it, we'd have to parse through possibly the entire document, make the changes accordingly and then the browser would have to parse through the entire thing and re-render the page entirely, cause it has no idea what actually changed. Maybe it can be smart and do some diff with the original document to only update relevant portions of its presentation. Either way, it's unwieldy.

But any modern browser presents a DOM interface to the underlying page document to JavaScript. Now, the browser isn't required to actually directly use this DOM for its rendering, but it should keep whatever's in there consistent with what you see on screen. If we think of this in the model-view-controller pattern that's prevalent for GUIs, then the DOM is the model, the browser's presentation is the view and now with JavaScript we actually also have a controller. If the controller (script) changes something to the underlying model (DOM), then the view (rendered page) gets updated accordingly. Since we're forced to go through the DOM, which is maintained by the browser, it'll notice whenever something gets changed. If the implementation is somewhat smart it'd have a listener that's notified whenever something goes through the DOM interface for an actual change.

You see, thanks to DOM, our scripts have direct access to any portion of the page, and since the model corresponds to the presentation, any changes can be quickly and efficiently propagated to the rendered stuff where it counts.

Now, the fact remains that DOM is general-purpose and models the actual markup. It doesn't really attribute meaning to it. We won't have some "hyperlink" objects to work with, we'll have "elements" with the name "a". And we won't have a "table" object with "tablerow" entries, we'll have elements with names "table" and in there elements with name "tr". Everything's some node like element, attribute or text without any meaning. It'd be nicer if there were any semantics involved instead of having us make sense of it. Like how JAXB does it in Java versus using DOM/JDOM/DOM4J or any similar solution.

But that's also its strength. Its generality lets us approach it in a uniform manner. It lets us apply stylesheets and write queries based on element names. It lets us introduce new elements in new versions of HTML without having to change DOM, since it's already got everything that's needed to represent those elements. DOM has been standardized by the W3C so we don't lock ourselves into browser-specific representations of documents. And the browser doesn't have to deal with yet another layer of abstraction and indirection that could harm performance.

These days, such abstraction is usually left to frameworks like JQuery which take some of the low-level details out of our hands. But at the basis it's still DOM that lets us do such stuff. It was essential in making dynamic HTML a reality, even before "ajax" became a word. If we wanted to abstract things further, we'd be looking at a new browser war regarding who gets to decide what model is best. We'd slow down HTML development (even more) because new stuff would need to be incorporated in the model, while DOM just models markup and thus has everything that's needed. `<canvas>` may be a big new thing that HTML 5 introduced which browsers now need to add support for, but for DOM it's just another element which happens to be called "canvas". Our JavaScript still works, so does our CSS.

So you see, DOM still has its place and its uses. But where once people were often quick to resort to it for any XML-related task, the available tools have become so numerous and good that these days you'll be using it as a last resort. But it's not on the way out yet. Maybe in the Java landscape, but not on lower levels.

Finally, regarding XQuery and FLWOR expressions... I've never used XQuery, only XPath. So I can't really draw any decent conclusions there without guessing.

Long rant, but in the evening I tend to get into this rambling flow of consciousness mode. What's good about Stack Overflow is that now I can actually use it to explain something to people who aren't imaginary. Beats pacing up and down the office while talking to walls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it is a very good one. Your explanation is brilliant but I am confused with those two points. Isn't XPATH the best answer to point (1)? I could not make a clear connection of point (2) and the rest of what you explain. Could you elaborate that with a use-case example? I completely forgot about Javascript targeting sections of a web document! If you use xquery for only some values, what do you think about FLWOR expressions? Many of my xqueries also retrieve long lists, but maybe because I am more functional-programming oriented. (updating now my question with XSLT)

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia This won't fit into a comment so I'll edit my post. Gimme a few minutes...

Comment: Thanks @G_H! Just some advices if you do not mind. Since you elaborate your points it would be more clear if you move the paragraphs related with point (1) below it. Also I believe I understand your point (2) but I cannot find a connection with a real life situation/example. For the rest it is a good answer. I am more interested in WHEN using DOM is exactly the right thing, but I appreciate a lot your other comments about when not to use it. In any case, I strongly believe that  DOM is badly overused in most cases because of a lack of knowledge about those alternatives.

Comment: comment to myself... FLWOR expressions are more oriented for transforming/crunching data, not for data retrieval that will be exported back to the query source

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia Yes, you are right. DOM is indeed, to this day, still frequently used by people who haven't investigated alternatives for what they're trying to do. I'd say DOM is the right thing if nothing else gets the job done, no sooner. And even then, if you at all have the possibility of only loading chunks of XML into DOM instead of the enitre (potentially big) XML document, that's still preferable.

Comment: OMG! you really worked hard for that answer @G_H. I would usually wait for more answers but I will choose yours right now. Now I remember when  JeffAtwood said that SO is a great place to learn writing. I believe that your answer is way too elaborate and suits better a blog post. I have mine because I write/think better there. I practice the art of being precise and direct here. Yours could be condensed into something shorter, but might loose some great info. Thanks!

Comment: How do you know we're not imaginary?

Comment: @TomAnderson, please dont confuse the guy. He might going on writing the book and I need to buy it! :-P

Comment: @FranciscoGarcia Being terse has certainly never been a quality of mine. Just ask anyone who has to wade through my JavaDoc. Anyway, I think a good use-case says more than specifications or technical discussion in this context. Also, I just really, really, really like to ramble. SO's given me an audience and man, do I like attention ;^_^

Answer (score 1):

I have very rarely decided that DOM was what i needed. But it has happened from time to time.

I have spent some time working with web testing frameworks. In essence, these suck in some (X)HTML, then let you make assertions about it. The natural way to do this is to parse the (X)HTML into a DOM tree, then inspect it. A lot of the inspection is done with XPath, but the XPath runs against the DOM. There is also a certain amount of direct manipulation - for instance, to check that some images on a web page are in the right order, i would write an XPath expression which selects the image elements, then loop over them, looking at the src and alt attributes of each one.

I once wrote a JAX-WS message handler, to juggle the namespaces on a message before sending it to an uncooperative web service (it didn't like default namespaces; i had to rewrite them all as prefixed namesapces). The easiest way to do that was to get the message as a DOM tree, then walk over it, manipulating the namespaces on each element as necessary.

I recently worked on a script to customise JBoss configuration files (i think it was the web deployer web.xml in particular). The idea was that we would read in the file as supplied with JBoss, apply some modifications, then write out the results. We wanted to express the modifications in a simple and portable way, so we wrote a Groovy script to manipulate the parsed HTML. This is not *quite* DOM, but it's close. In the end, it turned out to be very verbose and awkward, so we ended up using XPath and a command-line XML processor (XMLStarlet) instead.

The common factor in these cases was that i needed to read in some XML, manipulate it in some moderately complex, data-dependent, ways, and then often write it back out again. That's what DOM is good for.

You can also use XSLT for that, but frankly i would rather drill a hole in my head.

Comment: Good use-cases. I was actually gonna say XSLT would've been a better approach for the JAX-WS hack, but apparently you're not a fan :D What's the problem with XSLT? I've found it to be tremendously useful in many contexts.

Comment: I've found it to be unnecessarily fiddly to work with. XML is not a good format for programming languages, and i don't think XSLT's abstractions are very good either. I've always found it much, much easier to use some other tool.

Comment: My experience was that XSLT really shone once you learn to embrace its declarative style and avoid a procedural approach. And XPath is in my opinion one of its greatest strengths. The downside is that XSLT always seems to lack just that extra amount of functionality for doing things in a simple manner, requiring leaps of the imagination to get the job done. XSLT 2 is much better in this respect, but it just hasn't gained enough traction yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a qualification to previous answers. There are probably applications where using a DOM-like navigational tree interface makes sense. But don't be misled into thinking that DOM is the only or best API in this category. In the Java world, DOM is pretty horrible because of all its legacy (HTML, pre-namespaces) and because of all the baggage that has been added over the years. Other similar models such as JDOM and XOM are much cleaner and easier to use (and usually faster).

Comment: True words. Where Tom Anderson would rather suffer severe cranial trauma than use XSLT, I'd say the same for plain DOM in Java. Testing for node types feels as if you can't do anything but dive into anti-patterns. JDOM is really nice but memory use has prompted me to avoid it for anything but severely limited document sizes.